# MS Access chart create blank column

Tags: ms-access, charts

I'm working in MS Access 365 and is new to working with Access.

I have 2 problems getting a modern combo chart looking correct. Due to PO rules I had to split my post into two posts.
This post will adress one problem. My other problem is adressed in another post: [MS Access chart sort by month and department](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854967/ms-access-chart-sort-by-month-and-department)

I want to display cost of errors, for each department, for every month.
I have 8 departments, which I have listed in one table. I use a combobox on a form to populate fields in a 2nd table with department ID. This 2nd table also contains info about error cost and date.
I'm combining info from both tables in a query to generate my combo chart, formatting entry dates as Format([Oprettet_dato];"mmm") to get month abreviation.

Problem:
Departments without data for a given month create blank "month-column" in chart.

It's a new database and I've only got data going back 3 months. Therefore not all departments have errors registered. I have 2 departments without errors at all. I've included them in the query, by using left join, which works fine. Because they don't have a month assigned to them, I get blank fields in the month column of my query (as expected), but how do I get the chart to ignore the blank month entry, while still including the departments in the legend?

[My chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d33P.png)

```
SELECT T_Departments.Afdeling, Format([Oprettet_dato],"mmm") AS Periode, Sum(T_Errors.Samlet_økonomi) AS SumOfSamlet_økonomi
FROM T_Departments LEFT JOIN T_Errors ON T_Departments.Id = T_Errors.Afdeling
GROUP BY T_Departments.Afdeling, Format([Oprettet_dato],"mmm")
ORDER BY Max(T_Errors.Oprettet_dato);
```

[My query in design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KhVI.png)

I would prefer a build-in solution as I'm still learning the features of Access. I'm not familiar with sql code, but have done som VBA coding in Excel and will be able to do some coding if necessary.

Hope someone can help me.

I've added pictures of my query and my chart and the sql code for my query.

sincerely Mai

Comment: Suggestions provided in comments to your other question which you did not respond to. There is not really anything new here. You have not provided sample data as requested.

Comment: Chart can only build legend based on data. If you want legend to show an item that has no data, then build your own legend as a graphic that sits on or beside chart.

Comment: @June7 I'm waiting for my other question to be reopened for me to respond. I will look into building my own legend. Sounds like a possible solution. What kind of sample data do you need? I wanted to attach my database, but can't, so I added some sql code and pictures instead. I know it's not the best sample data, but I don't know how to add anything else.

Comment: I doubt your other question will get reopened. At this point, also doubt providing data will be of benefit. Might consider posting to a forum that allows attaching files as well as discussion format.

Comment: Can make comments to closed questions.

Answer (score 0):

My actual answer is to export your data to a program like Excel or R that has better charts where you can manually adjust the scale and appearance of the x and y axis.  You can even automate the process so that when you open your report the updated data is exported processed and then the reports chart is updated.
To answer the question asked, I chose to get Access to show the missing columns by setting them equal to -1.  Add a label or something to your report to point that out.

Next we create the perfect query for the record source of the chart.  For every combination of month and department (cross-join) we calculate the sum of Amount.
Note that Departments and Errors are related by DepartmentID in both tables.  but in this query we delete the relationship.  When you query unrelated tables you get the cross-join of all included table fields.  so all that remains is that way too complicated calculated field called sum.

[image]

```
sum: IIf(Nz(DSum("Amount","Errors","MonthofError = '" & [MonthofError] & "' AND DepartmentID = " & DLookUp("DepartmentID","Departments","DepartmentName = '" & [DepartmentName] & "'")),0)=0,-1,DSum("Amount","Errors","MonthofError = '" & [MonthofError] & "' AND DepartmentID = " & DLookUp("DepartmentID","Departments","DepartmentName = '" & [DepartmentName] & "'")))

english: sum amount from table Errors for each month and department.  treat no amount as 0. if for a given month and department the sum is 0 then set the sum to -1 so it can be seen.

'Departments
DepartmentID    DepartmentName
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h

'Errors
ErrorID DepartmentID    MonthofError    Amount
1   1   August  10
2   1   September   0
3   1   August  10
4   2   August  0
5   2   September   10
6   2   October 10
7   4   August  10
8   4   September   10
9   4   October 10
10  6   August  10
11  6   September   10
12  6   October 10
13  8   August  10
14  8   September   10
15  8   October 10
```

then use the query as the basis for a chart in your form or report.

[image]

Comment: Thank you mazoula. I think I will go with the Excel export method for now as I have a deadline for a report. Then I will see if I should automate that solution or test your second solution.

Comment: Unlike in Access when you export from Excel you can get the VBA code.  That VBA code can be helpful both in access and for fine tuning or automating Excel.